# UICollectionView using sections leaves a gap between cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using a UICollectionView to show several sections of data. These sections have a fixed number of items. I want all the items to show in a continuous grid.

Right now I accomplish this in horizontal orientation:
[image]

But in vertical this leaves a big gap:
[image]

I want to solve this gap between sections because it's ugly and it doesn't belong there.
I'd be happy to use a custom FlowLayout, but I can't find a tutorial that points me in the right direction (I've found several, but none of them really touch this problem specifically.)

Can anybody help me solve this problem, or at least point me in the right direction?

P.S: I've implemented sections because I'm loading the data on the fly. Using 1 section isn't an option for me at this moment.

*UPDATE*
On request I'm adding the values used for my current FlowLayout. I'm using the standard Horizontal Flow Layout on a fullscreen (minus UINavigationBar) UICollectionView with 21 items per section.

- Scroll direction: Horizontal
- Cell size: 248, 196
- Header / footer size: none
- Min spacing for cells: 10
- Min spacing for lines: 10
- Section Insets: 20, 20, 10, 10

Comment: Edit your post to include all of the sizing parameters you're setting on the flow layout, so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem isn't the gap. The problem is the number of items in each section. You have four rows. If your count of items for that section is not a multiple of four then it cannot display a complete section and so it leaves a gap before moving to the next section. It's almost like you want "inline" sections?

Comment: Hmm.. fogmeister didn't really gave me the solution I was looking for (I would still want to know how I could solve this issue with 21 items in a section) but he did trigger me to try a multiply of 4 (and 3, to support landscape) and if I use 24 items in a section it turns out the gap problem is solved.. interesting! thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**Use like this**

It will solve Gap problem

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2;
```

Comment: He's talking about the section gaps, not the spacing between sections.

Answer (score 1):

To remove those gaps you need to create custom layout which will act as layout for your collection view. This class will child class for UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Then you can override below two methods and can create your own custom layout as you want.

```
  - (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
  - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
```

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes is class which will deal with cell position, frame, Zindex etc

You can also use below properties.

```
 collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
 collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```